# ajax call getting error in primefaces when executing

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am having the below code in my .xhtml file. making ajax(p:ajax) call but i got below error when i execute the page. is their any possible solution for this?

```
 <p:ajax> Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

code:

```
  <h:panelGrid  columns="3" rules="group" width="100%" border="0">
    <p:column ><h:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;font-size:15px" for="search_dia" value="Diameter:"/> 
    </p:column>
  <p:column><p:inputText styleClass ="search_di" id="search_dia"  value="#{searchRequest.diameter}" >
     <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out1" /></p:inputText>
  </p:column>
 <h:outputText id="out1" value="#{searchRequest.diameter}" />  
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Which version of Primefaces do you use?

Comment: This should be perfectly legal (see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyKeyEvents.jsf). As suggested by miroslav_mijajlovic, Primefaces version is important (you may have a look at this issue: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3118)